# Room Database Empty when Restarted App ( Same DB Name)

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am newbie to the Android X Room Database. Earlier I used Sqlitehelper class to access the sqlite databases and then migrated to room. The question is , when I insert data into Room database table it stores for that moment and when I restart the app the data is gone. I want to have multiple tables in a single database.

DAO :

```
@androidx.room.Dao
public interface ItineraryDao {


@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
void insert(ItineraryData model);

@Update
void update(ItineraryData model);

@Delete
void delete(ItineraryData model);

@Query("DELETE FROM "+ CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE)
void deleteAllItinerary();

@Query("SELECT * FROM "+CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE+" ORDER BY Date ASC")
LiveData<List<ItineraryData>> getAllItinerary();
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = {ItineraryData.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract  class ItineraryDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static ItineraryDatabase instance;
public abstract ItineraryDao Dao();

public static synchronized ItineraryDatabase getInstance(Context mCon){
    if (instance == null) {
        instance =
              Room.databaseBuilder(mCon.getApplicationContext(),
                                ItineraryDatabase.class, CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE)
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(roomCallback)
                        .build();
    }
  
    return instance;

}

private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
  
        new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
    }
};
private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    PopulateDbAsyncTask(ItineraryDatabase instance) {
        ItineraryDao dao = instance.Dao();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return null;
    }
```

The above is the code I used is every table to generate table with different Dao's . As I need to create the tablets in a single database i used same CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE for all of them. If I use differnt names in CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE this works fine. But it creates different databases.

How can I create multiple tables in a single database without loosing data on restart. I went thorugh some earlier posts. But they suggest to use different database names.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create multiple tables in a single database without loosing data on restart.

You define multiple tables by specifying multiple `@Entity` annotated classes in the entities parameter of the `@Database` annotation.

That is how you tell Room what tables will be created.

Where you use `ItineraryDatabase.class, CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE`, this is telling Room that the database (i.e. the file name) will be named as per `CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE`.

I suspect that you want the same table layout/schema but multiple tables (possibly itself not a good idea as each table has overheads when a single column could indicate the equivalent of the row belonging to a specific set of data).

- ***you may wish to edit your question to say more about what you are trying to achieve and you may therefore get more elaborate and specific answers.*** If you do then feel free to notify myself by comment as such to this answer. At the minimum I would then look at any changes, but there is a very good chance that I would elaborate.

**Additional (DEMO)**

Considering the comment:-

> I want to have different table with different table schema's in a single database file. I have seperate entity classes for them. Do i need to have getinstance for each table in this single class ( which extends with roomdatabase) ? One Database Class with multiple getinstance?

and also the presumption of a single schema (not that it matters much if not, simpler if not). Then consider the following code that is based very much on your code.

**ItineraryData** (used as a model for two tables, so not @Entity annotated - can be ignored if different schemas);-

```
class ItineraryData {
   @PrimaryKey
   Long id=null;
   long date=System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
   @NonNull
   String otherColumn;
}
```

**CONSTANTS** :-

```
class CONSTANTS {
   static final String ITINERARY_TABLE = "it01";
   static final String ITINERARY_TABLE_2 = "it02";
}
```

**ItineraryTable01** (bit of a cheat as schema grabbed from ItineraryData) :-

```
@Entity(tableName = CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE)
class ItineraryTable01 extends ItineraryData {
}
```

**ItineraryTable02** (cheat again):-

```
@Entity(tableName = CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE_2)
class ItineraryTable02 extends ItineraryData {
}
```

**ItineraryDao**

```
@Dao
public interface ItineraryDao {
   
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   void insert(ItineraryTable01 model);
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   void insert(ItineraryTable02 model);

   @Update
   void update(ItineraryTable01 model);
   @Update
   void update(ItineraryTable02 model);

   @Delete
   void delete(ItineraryTable01 model);
   @Delete
   void delete(ItineraryTable02 model);

   @Query("DELETE FROM " + CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE)
   void deleteAllItineraryTable01();
   @Query("DELETE FROM " + CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE_2)
   void deleteAllItineraryTable02();

   @Query("SELECT * FROM " + CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE + " ORDER BY Date ASC")
   /*LiveData<*/List<ItineraryTable01>/*>*/ getAllItineraryTable01();
   @Query("SELECT * FROM " + CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE + " ORDER BY Date ASC")
      /*LiveData<*/List<ItineraryTable02>/*>*/ getAllItineraryTable02();
}
```

- commented out LiveData so can run on MainThread (although queries not used in demo, but just in case)
- note the close duplications for each table.

**ItineraryDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = { ItineraryTable01.class,ItineraryTable02.class/*ItineraryData.class*/} ,version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract  class ItineraryDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

   private static ItineraryDatabase instance;

   public abstract ItineraryDao Dao();

   public static synchronized ItineraryDatabase getInstance(Context mCon) {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance =
                 Room.databaseBuilder(mCon.getApplicationContext(),
                                 ItineraryDatabase.class, CONSTANTS.ITINERARY_TABLE)
                         .allowMainThreadQueries() /*<<<<<<<<<< Added for convenience brevity of demo */
                         .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                         .addCallback(roomCallback)
                         .build();
      }
      return instance;

   }

   private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
         super.onCreate(db);

         new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
      }
   };

   private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
      PopulateDbAsyncTask(ItineraryDatabase instance) {
         ItineraryDao dao = instance.Dao();
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
         return null;
      }
   }
}
```

- allow to run on Main thread, otherwise unchanged (no need for callback though, it does nothing)

Finally to demo some code in an activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ItineraryDatabase db;
    ItineraryDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ItineraryTable01 it01 = new ItineraryTable01();
        ItineraryTable02 it02 = new ItineraryTable02();

        it01.otherColumn = "blah01";
        it02.otherColumn = "blah02";

        db = ItineraryDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.Dao();
        /* Not until following code is executed is the database actually opened */
        dao.insert(it01); /* Inserts into table01 */
        dao.insert(it02); /* Inserts into table02 */

    }
}
```

**Results**

**When first run**

Using App Inspection:-

[image]

and

[image]

**Run again** (aka rerun)

[image]

and

[image]

- as can be seen the data (rows highlighted) from the first run has been retained and data from the second run has been added (different generated id's and timestamps)

Comment: I want to have different table with different table schema's in a single database file. I have seperate entity classes for them. Do i need to have getinstance for each table in this single class ( which extends with roomdatabase) ?  One Database Class with multiple getinstance?

Comment: The **getInstance** is for the Database as a whole. Getting the instance (or instances) of the @Dao annotated interface(s) is what then allows you to access (do things) according to table. E.g. say you have table1 and table2 (classes named accordingly) then you could have; '@Insert long insert(Table1 table);' and '@Insert long insert(Table2 table);' for inserting into both tables.

Comment: @SupunAyeshmantha answer updated which I believe explains the comments. See **Additional** section.